# How to combine jigsaw with regular tikz commands?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to use the jigsaw pieces in a larger tikzpicture and use the regular commands such as “below of” or draw paths between the pieces. In the orginal document though pieces are put in separate environments. The definition \piece doesn't allow using a code such as the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{jigsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0};
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}; % below of piece 1
\path (piece1) edge (piece2); %path from piece1 to piece2
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Figured out a solution with "shift". When substracting -0.5cm from the designated mid of the puzzle piece it works.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (center) {Center1};
\node at (5,0) (center2) {Center2};
\begin{scope}[shift={(center2)},local bounding box=piece1,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(center2)},local bounding box=piece2,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(center2)},local bounding box=piece3,xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=1.5cm]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(center2)}, local bounding box=piece4,xshift=-2.5cm,yshift=-2.5cm]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\path (piece1) edge (piece2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The correct way apparently is to place it in a scope environ  for each piece if you want run additional tikz commands -- the (very short)manual is available at --  http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/jigsaw/jigsaw-doc.tex

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{jigsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\piece[teal]{1}{-1}{0}{0};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
\piece[violet]{1}{-1}{0}{0};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `local bounding box`es to connect these jigsaw pieces.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{jigsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=piece1]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=piece2,yshift=-2cm]
\piece{1}{-1}{0}{0} % below of piece 1
\end{scope}
\path (piece1.south west) edge (piece2.north west); %path from piece1 to piece2
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]